# Prestashop - Right way to make AJAX request to CategoryController

Tags: php, json, ajax, prestashop

I need to make an AJAX call to override the Front Controller. The last way I've tried returns a `403` Status Code, but in the `responseText` it shows me the correct JSON.

How do I reconcile that and fix it so it properly returns a `200 OK` along with the correct JSON?

```
<?php
class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        // check if URL contain ajax option and set it.
        if( $this->ajax = Tools::getValue( "ajax" ) ){
            if( $this->ajax ){
                $action = Tools::getValue( 'action' );

                if( !empty( $action ) && method_exists( $this, 'ajaxProcess' . Tools::toCamelCase( $action ) ) ){
                    // Return the method call
                    $this->{'ajaxProcess' . Tools::toCamelCase( $action )}();
                } else {
                    $this->AjaxProcess();
                }
                // Required to avoid errorHandler in AJAX
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    public function ajaxProcessMyAjaxMethod()
    {
        $customerId = Tools::getValue( 'customerId' );
        print Tools::jsonEncode( array(
            'customerId' => $customerId,
            'msg'        => 'Hello PS AJAX!!!',
            ) );
    }
}
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUri + 'index.php',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      controller: 'Category',
      action: 'MyAjaxMethod',
      customerId: 45,
      ajax: 1,
      token: token
    },
  })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: show the code that you used for.

Comment: Witch version of Prestashop are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoryController` must get `id_category` to run successfully. You can add it there:

```
   ...
    data: {
        controller: 'Category', /* better lowercase 'category' */
        id_category: 3, /* your ID category */
        action: 'MyAjaxMethod', /* if you are using 'toCamelCase', it can be 'my_ajax_method' */
        customerId: 45,
        ajax: 1,
        token: token
    }
   ...
```

Please be sure you are passing it to the right url (so `url: baseUri + 'index.php'` is correct) .

Comment: I'm passing the right URL `baseUri` is a Prestashop variable so generated url is something like `http://domain.local/index.php`. Just to know... why should I pass id_category?

Comment: `CategoryController` is for displaying all information related to a category page. Without a category ID it does not make sense, so a `Dispatcher` is preventing from errors like that.